# SPARQL query to get capacity of event venues from Wikidata

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I am trying to query Wikidata to find out the capacities of all event venues in specific geographic regions (US urban centers). They have this service for querying: [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Farena%20%3FarenaLabel%20%3Fmaximum_capacity%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%3Farena%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ641226.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Farena%20wdt%3AP1083%20%3Fmaximum_capacity.%20%7D%0A%7D)

The answer in the related question below gave this query as an example for getting the capacities of arenas:

```
SELECT ?arena ?arenaLabel ?maximum_capacity WHERE {

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language " 
   [AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

  ?arena wdt:P31 wd:Q641226.
  OPTIONAL { ?arena wdt:P1083 ?maximum_capacity. }
}
```

I tried to modify it a bit to get the capacities of event venues, not just arenas, but I don't get any results:

```
SELECT ?venue ?maximum_capacity WHERE {

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language " 
   [AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

  ?venue wdt:P31 wd:Q7463935.

  OPTIONAL { ?venue wdt:P1083 ?maximum_capacity. }
}
```

I think the issue partly is that [wd:Q7463935](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q7463935) says 'Category' so maybe 'wdt:P31' = 'is instance of' is not the correct way to phrase this.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Related Question: [Capacity/attendance information for US event venues](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15249/capacity-attendance-information-for-us-event-venues/15253#15253)

Comment: Basically, like this: https://w.wiki/4GX